# Pandas merging dataframes creates nan columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge 3x2 excels (3x sets of data, one for male and female) into one big dataframe. Each excel can contain different people.

Each dataframe currently exists of 4 columns: `Lidnummer`, `Speler`, `Club`, `Klassement`.

Each excel looks something like the following

```
| Lidnummer | Speler | Club | Klassement |
|-----------|--------|------|------------|
| 1         | some1  | meh  | A          |
| 2         | some2  | meh  | D          |
| 3         | some3  | meh  | B2         |
```

This exists for each gender and each discipline (`s`, `x`, `d`)

So I wrote the following code block to read each dataset

```
single_male = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=0)[['Lidnummer', 'Speler', 'Club', 'Klassement']].rename(index=str, columns={'Klassement': 's'}).assign(d=np.nan, x=np.nan, gender='M')
single_female = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=1)[['Lidnummer','Speler', 'Club', 'Klassement']].rename(index=str, columns={'Klassement': 's'}).assign(d=np.nan, x=np.nan, gender='F')
double_male = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=2)[['Lidnummer','Speler', 'Club', 'Klassement']].rename(index=str, columns={'Klassement': 'd'}).assign(s=np.nan, x=np.nan, gender='M')
double_female = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=3)[['Lidnummer','Speler', 'Club', 'Klassement']].rename(index=str, columns={'Klassement': 'd'}).assign(s=np.nan, x=np.nan, gender='F')
mix_male = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=4)[['Lidnummer','Speler', 'Club', 'Klassement']].rename(index=str, columns={'Klassement': 'x'}).assign(d=np.nan, s=np.nan, gender='M')
mix_female = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=5)[['Lidnummer','Speler', 'Club', 'Klassement']].rename(index=str, columns={'Klassement': 'x'}).assign(d=np.nan, s=np.nan, gender='F')
```

This puts the data as I would think is needed for merging. I merge it as following

```
dataFrames = [single_male, single_female, double_male, double_female, mix_male, mix_female]
players = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Lidnummer','Speler', 'Club', 'gender'], how='outer'), dataFrames)
players.head()
```

This seems to work, except it creates the column `s_x`, `s_y`, `d_x`, `d_y`, `x_x`, `x_y`. and the data is split over those 2 columns for each discipline (s, d and x).

Some googling suggest to include e.g. `'s'` in the `on=` part of the merge but then I get the error

`You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

I've tried using concat, but I couldn't get it to work.

So how can I make a single column for `s`, `d` and `x` containing the data for each discipline?

So the resulting dataset would look like:

```
| Lidnummer | Speler | Club | gender | s  | d   | x  |
|-----------|--------|------|--------|----|-----|----|
| 1         | some1  | meh  | M      | A  | A   | A  |
| 2         | some2  | meh  | F      | D  | C2  | C1 |
| 3         | some3  | meh  | F      | B2 | B1  | B2 |
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Isn't it just that you want to have one DataFrame with all the rows of all your 6 sheets (after doing your transformations)?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I've updated the question with some additional info

Comment: Btw. does the code, you presented here run e.g. the `rename` (looks ambiguous somehow)? So you want your sheets concatenated together, that's an easy one..

Comment: Is it? what I've found on the concatenated is that in my case when each excel has different amount of players (not everyone exists in all datasheets) it doesn't work so well

Comment: The way you used it, would join the dataframes columnwise. So to one of the female players frame it searches a match in the other frame and adds columns for it, but as I understood that is not what you want. Can you try the code below and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code (have no excel here):

```
columns= ['Lidnummer', 'Speler', 'Club', 'Klassement']
single_male = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=0)[columns]
single_male['gender']='M'

single_female = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=1)[columns]
single_male['gender']='F'

double_male = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=2)[columns]
single_male['gender']='M'

double_female = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=3)[columns]
single_male['gender']='F'

mix_male = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=4)[columns]
single_male['gender']='M'

mix_female = pd.read_excel(xlxs, sheet_name=5)[columns]
single_male['gender']='F'

all= pd.concat([single_male, single_female, double_male. double_female, mix_male, mix_female], axis='index', ignore_index=True)

all.rename({'Klassement': 's'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
all['d']= all['s']
all['x']= all['s']
```

Comment: I just mentioned this in the other comment section: How does this merges the data? can it work with single_male and double_male being different sets of persons?

Comment: Yes, it just glues the frames together. Say if you have 4 rows in the "male dataframe" and 3 in the "female dataframe", you get 7 records if you do `pd.concat([male, female], axis='index')`. The important part here is `axis='index'` this glues the rows together in index direction. If you do `axis='columns'` it would try to allign the data column-wise.

Comment: I think I missed a detail, the columns `s`, `d`, `x` are different sets of data, and so what I see from your code, this doesn't take this in account.

Comment: Hmm, in your post it looks like you filled them with `Nan`. Are they actually columns in your excel? if so, you just need to add them to the columns list and if necessary add them to the dict passed to `all.rename`.

Comment: Sorry, I have to go now, I have a course at 12:30. Hope this helps you to figure the rest out yourself. Pandas is fun.

Comment: No problem, thanks already for the help. I'm going to play with your code and hopefully I get there :)

Comment: I've updated the solution with what I did to get something that look like it's working :)

Comment: Great! when I was on my way I was not so sure anymore about the s, d, x columns. I thought what you really needed was probably something pivot table like. Let me know, if you have any problems, then we can figure it out together.